# Spring Shell - command Prompt exits immediately, does not await user input

Tags: java, spring, command-line-interface, spring-shell

I am attempting to build a Spring Shell application. 
I am able to run my application successfully but it exits immediately @ startup & does not await user input. It seems to not remain in the JLineShell promptLoop method.

I am building a jar with a mainClassName = "org.springframework.shell.Bootstrap".

My spring-shell-plugin.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.zailab" />

</beans>
```

My Main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Bootstrap.main(args);
}

}
```

My Command class:

```
@Component
public class BuildCommand implements CommandMarker {

@CliAvailabilityIndicator({"echo"})
  public boolean isCommandAvailable() {
    return true;
  }

@CliCommand(value = "echo", help = "Echo a message")
 public String echo(
   @CliOption(key = { "", "msg" }, mandatory = true, help= "The message to echo") String msg) {
  return msg;
 }

}
```

Comment: Please post some code/configuration.

Comment: May not be the root cause, but why have a Main class that does nothing but delegate to the Bootsrap class? Also, is you appcontext xml file correctly placed and visible under /META-INF/spring/spring-shell-plugin.xml

Comment: I have since changed the Main class & now delegate to Bootstrap itself. I can confirm that the spring-shell-plugin.xml is correctly placed & visible. It seems the problem is an EOF returned from the ConsoleReader immediately.

Comment: please specify in your question on how you are running it. either from your ide or outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what the issue was. Do not attempt to start the shell from within an IDE(STS to be exact). It seems an EOF is returned immediately when running the app from within the IDE, works perfectly via command line.

Thanks

Comment: This has to do with on how IDE works. Just pass the params as Cengiz did answer and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

You can also start your app in IDE without returning immediately.

You have to put the following JVM parameters to your run configuration:

for *nix machines:

```
-Djline.terminal=org.springframework.shell.core.IdeTerminal
```

for Windows machines:

```
-Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
```