# Spring shell 3 - StringInputContext not prompting for input?

Tags: spring, spring-shell

I set up a new project using `spring-boot(-shell) 3.0.3` and I'm just trying to capture some inputs and return them. When I pass in the arguments using ShellOption everything works fine, but I wanted to try out a bit more of the framework and use the input components.

However I'm getting no error when running it from powershell, yet I am also not getting prompted for my input despite following the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/3.0.x/docs/#using-shell-components albeit with the caveat of using the new `StringInputContext` location since the one in the docs is seemingly now an embedded class.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction, here's a simplified snippet:

```
@ShellComponent
public class SomeCommand extends AbstractShellComponent {

     @ShellMethod(value = "Ask and return2")
    public String ask2() {
        StringInput component = new StringInput(getTerminal(), "What to return?", "");
        component.setResourceLoader(getResourceLoader());
        component.setTemplateExecutor(getTemplateExecutor());
        StringInput.StringInputContext context = component.run(StringInput.StringInputContext.empty());
        return context.getResultValue();
    }
}
```

I saw [Spring Shell - command Prompt exits immediately, does not await user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991910/spring-shell-command-prompt-exits-immediately-does-not-await-user-input) but I am not opening the prompt from within IntelliJ, but from within powershell & cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies are minimal: you may use JLine without any dependency on *nix systems, but in order to support windows or more advanced usage, you will need to add either Jansi or JNA library.